# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 problem 17.b

Tags: calculus

Prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1} $$

Does not exist.

What I did was:
Say $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1} = L $$

- ∃ ε > 0 : ∀ δ > 0 ∃x with |x-1| < δ and  |$\frac{1}{x-1}$ -L| ≥ ε

I do not know how to proceed, how can I find that ε and x?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$, then $f(1+ \frac{1}{n})=n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

We'll push the limit off to infinity, where it belongs.

Fix $M>0$. Then choosing $\delta=\frac{1}{M}$ yields 
$$
|x-1|<\frac{1}{M}\implies \frac{1}{|x-1|}>M
$$

If this is not convincing enough, you may suppose a finite limit $L$, and estimate
$$
\left | \frac{1}{x-1}-L\right |\geq \left | \frac{1}{|x-1|}-|L|\right|
$$
convince yourself that taking $\frac{1}{|x-1|}\geq |L|+1$ does the trick.

Comment: I am finding difficult to prove a limit does not exist.
In your case $\epsilon = 1 $ right?

Comment: that's right ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's approach the function from the left
For this let's put $x$ to be a little less than 1
For this we can write $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{x-1}$ as $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{(1-h)-1}$$ that would equal $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{-h}$$ Putting h as zero, we would find that this expression would tend to -∞ from the left.

Similarly, putting $x$ as $1+h$ in the given function, where $h\to0$ would give us that the function tends to +∞ from the right.

As the limits from the left and right are unequal, the function's limit is not defined at $x\to1$